# Javadoc Ant Task not working as expected on Ubuntu machine

Tags: java, ubuntu, ant, jenkins, javadoc

I have a Jenkins instance running on a remote Ubuntu machine and I am trying to use the [Javadoc Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Javadoc+Plugin) on it. The project uses Ant so I decided to use the [Javadoc Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html) to generate the documentation and the Jenkins plugin to publish it.

I have setup a simple target that looks like this:

```
<target name="doc" description="generate javadoc">
    <javadoc 
        destdir="${basedir}/javadocs"
        sourcepath="${basedir}/src"
        packagenames="com.example.*"
        failonerror="false"
    />
</target>
```

When I run it from the command line on my Windows 7 machine it works fine and produces the appropriate Javadoc in the specified ${basedir}/javadoc/ directory. But when I run it on the Ubuntu machine it only creates the ${baseir}/javadoc/ directory, it does not generate the actual Javadoc.

When comparing the output of the two different runs I noticed that on the Ubuntu machine it never makes it to the step that starts with:

```
[javadoc] Constructing Javadoc information...
```

Instead it stops at:

```
[javadoc] [parsing completed 43ms]
```

I have tried to turn on verbose mode for the Ant task and it has not given me any useful information. Has any one seen this happen before? Is there anything I can do to fix this problem or at least get Ant to tell me why it is stopping before "Constructing Javadoc information"? Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: a) have you tried to base the `sourcepath` attribute on `${basedir}`? b) on my system (not Ubuntu) the `javadoc` ant task complains if neither the `packagenames` attribute or a `fileset` nested-element is designated; maybe with your Ubuntu that fails silently.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have tried changing a few different attributes with mixed results. What I currently have is in my edit. This still works on Windows 7 but not Ubuntu. I ended up cloning the Ant repo and running their javadoc task which worked and produced the expected result so I'm not really sure what's going on. If you have any other tips I would appreciate it. Thanks again.

Comment: The only other cause I can think of is, you might be using different doclets on your respective OSes unknowingly. Every doclet has a behavior on its own. So varying the doclet on Ubuntu may help you to identify the issue.

Comment: So I ended out uploading the jar that my windows 7 machine was getting the doclet from to the Ubuntu machine and explicitly calling it in both the ant task and from the javadoc command. Neither worked. They both stopped after parsing and then exited with error 1. There is no context for the error though so I'm not sure where to go. Thanks for the help.